# SCTP over UDP implementation in Netty

Tags: java, udp, netty, sctp

Is there a way to use Netty to achieve SCTP over UDP.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6951

I am looking to implement both Client and Server.

Comment: Too broad. You'll have enough trouble implementing it as an SCTPSocketChannel let alone getting Netty's semantics to agree with it.

Comment: any stable java library which we can use for SCTP over DTLS over UDP similar to what we have in webrtc?